# How to Route some page without sidebar in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React js. I have a sidebar and some page and a login page, but I want to show the login page without sidebar and then sidebar with content body.
Here is my code:

```js
function App() {
   return (
      <Router>
          <Sidebar />
          <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={InfiniteScroll} />
          <Route path='/tableHook' exact component={TableHook} /> 
          <Route path='/ticket' exact component={Tickets} />
          <Route path='/newTicket' exact component={NewTicket}/>
          <Route path='/LastTable' exact component={LastTable} />
          <Route path='/answer' exact component={Answerticket} />
          <Route path='/ingredientFood' exact component={Ingredient} />
          <Route path='/setting' exact component={Setting}/>
          </Switch>
      </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional rendering. I guess your landing page Url path is `<Route path='/' exact component={InfiniteScroll} />`. So if you do this it should work.

```
 function App() {
  

   return (
  
      <Router>
          
        
        { window.location.pathname != '/' &&  <Sidebar /> }
          <Switch>
       
          <Route path='/' exact component={InfiniteScroll} />
          <Route path='/tableHook' exact component={TableHook} /> 
          <Route path='/ticket' exact component={Tickets} />
          <Route path='/newTicket' exact component={NewTicket}/>
          <Route path='/LastTable' exact component={LastTable} />
          <Route path='/answer' exact component={Answerticket} />
          <Route path='/ingredientFood' exact component={Ingredient} />
          <Route path='/setting' exact component={Setting}/>

 </Switch>
      </Router>
    
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have similar kind of functionality in our app and we have implemented it something like this -

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <React.Fragment>
        <Switch>
          {
            <Route exact="/">
              {
                JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn')) ?
                  <MainApp /> : <Login />
              }
            </Route>
          }
        </Switch>
      </React.Fragment>
</BrowserRouter>
```

You do not have to necessarily use `localStorage`. You can use a state `isLoggedIn` and default it to `false`. Render logic will remain the same and once the user is authenticated successfully you can update the value of `isLoggedIn` to `true`